# jQuery: how do i set text in ajaxComplete method but fade it in rather than display immediately

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am an admitted jquery noob, learning the library via the api documentation and jsfiddle. I am currently trying to understand why the following is not working as I am expecting.

Here's the simple section of html

```
<div class="trigger">Trigger</div>
<div class="result"></div>
<div class="log"></div>
```

and here's the jquery I am trying...

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url === "ajax/test.html") {        
        $(".log").hide();
        $("Triggered ajaxComplete handler. The result is " + xhr.statusText).appendTo(".log").fadein();
    }
});

$(".trigger").click(function () {
    $(".result").load("ajax/test.html");
});
```

Unfortunately what appears to be happening is that the append operation is not executing correctly as an unhandled exception is being thrown because the text "Triggered ajax..." is being treated as if it were a selector, but my understanding of the appendTo() function from reading the [jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) is that you can create content on the fly like this. Obviously I'm going wrong somewhere obvious and would be grateful to anyone who could explain why this is wrong and what I can do to correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.text()` instead.

```
$(".log").hide()
         .text("Triggered ajaxComplete handler. The result is " + xhr.statusText)
         .fadeIn();
```

Otherwise, you need to use `.append()` instead.

```
$(".log").hide()
         .append("Triggered ajaxComplete handler. The result is " + xhr.statusText)
         .fadeIn();
```

Notice these two methods are not the same. The former will replace the content of `.log` and the latter will append text to `.log`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".log").html("Triggered ajaxComplete handler. The result is " + xhr.statusText)
     .fadeIn();
```